# Ignore specific files (not directory) while running pytest and pytest-cov

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov

I have project structure as:

```
myproject
 src
   -routes.py
   -services.py
   -data_access.py
 tests
   -test_routes.py
   -test_services.py
```

I want to run the tests with coverage on **src** but want to exclue **src/data_access.py**.

I want to implement something similar to:
**pytest tests --cov=src --exclude=src/data_access.py** but *exclude* is not the right argument.

Answer (score 1):

@Anu is right, but didn't fully explained.

You need to create .coveragerc file to the root of your project.(If you don't then you need to specify where is it).

In that file add:
[run]
omit = ./*
This will remove all the folders from coverage, considering that you're currently in the root of the project.
If you need to include specific files, use include = ... instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add coveragerc and use the —omit option.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip specific files from inside the `setup.cfg` pytest section, like this:

```
[tool:pytest]
addopts = --ignore=src/data_access.py
```

You can append it multiple times to ignore more files.